# Set action when an item from combobox is selected

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am working on a project where I have ComboBox in a pane, which has "Games", "Albums", and "Movies".

I want to open another Pane when one of these is selected.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
GridPane select = new GridPane();
select.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
select.setHgap(6.5);
select.setVgap(6.5);
select.add(new Label("Media Type"), 0, 1)

ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();

comboBox.getItems().add("Movies");
comboBox.getItems().add("Albums");
comboBox.getItems().add("Games");

HBox hbox = new HBox(comboBox);

Scene thirdScene = new Scene(hbox, 500, 500);
Stage thirdStage = new Stage();

thirdStage.setScene(thirdScene); 
thirdStage.setTitle("Media Menu");
thirdStage.show();
```

Comment: [Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMSeb1HO_y8).

Comment: work through a tutorial about how to use combebox, apply what you learned when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to go through the API (java doc) of controls you use to have a quick idea of what they are capable of.

You can either listen to the valueProperty or selectedItemProperty or you can set an action.

```
comboBox.setOnAction(e->{
  String value= comboBox.getValue();
  ... // Do the stuff with value
});
```

or

```
comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs,old,value)->{
    ... // Do the stuff with value
});
```

or

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,old,value)->{
    ... // Do the stuff with value
});
```